# Desargues Configuration

Tags: projective-geometry

Section 3.2 of Coxeter's *Projective Geometery* discusses the self-dual $10_3$ configuration, ten points and ten lines, with three pointson each line and three lines through each point.

I am looking at the Figure 2.3a, but I am having trouble trying to find $P_1S$, where are the "exterior" points.

Could someone please tell me of a link, book, or at all else draw or clearly explain where these points line?

Comment: I don't have the book here (though I might be able to take a look tomorrow). Have you seen [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/654358/35416)? It might help understanding the combinatorics of this configuration, and the fact that all points are essentially equivalent (i.e. there is a relabeling which exchanges their roles but preserves the combinatorics), so distinguishing some as “exterior” might be wrong. It also illustrates the duality, via set complement.

Comment: @MvG, thanks! Didn't see that when tried searching on this site.